# Is there a way to cache audio element requests without Service Workers?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, tampermonkey, flac

I have a userscript where I'd like to cache audio files from audio elements. `fetch()` isn't viable here as I have to wait for it to fetch to get a blob out of it. Is there a way to use the audio element itself for caching? The codec of the audio is FLAC.

Comment: `fetch() isn't viable here as I have to wait for it` how is that an issue?

Comment: there is also this [mdn : Request: cache property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache)

Comment: @JaromandaX As I have to wait for the fetch to finish, the audio doesn't start playing immediately after the play button is pressed and that's suboptimal even if it works

Comment: OK then I totally misunderstand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I have audio links which I must cache when they're played. I can't use fetch() as that would require waiting for the entire file to fetch, which is much slower compared to a serviceWorker, which can clone a request from an audio element so that the audio plays normally and gets cached when it's fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the appropriate [`Cache-Control` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), the browser will cache for you.  No other work is required.

For example:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800, immutable
```

Comment: that would require access to the server - at a guess, since OP is using `tampermonkey`, they are trying to do this on a site that isn't theirs?

Comment: @JaromandaX Tampermonkey can't alter response headers?  I've never used it myself, but it seems like it should be able to, yeah?

Comment: You may be right, been years since I used it :p

Comment: I don't think Cache-Control can be used here as all the URL parameters change per visit except for one

Comment: @SeetheMoar Sad.  In that case, yeah you need a Service Worker.